# SobiPro Export - Infinite Loop

Tags: php, mysql, sobipro

The code below is an export tool, I am essentially querying the database of SobiPro, pulling a list of Entries (Companies) and also the associated custom fields.

I have stumbled on an infinite loop here. Some parts are there for simply noting an ID, so disregard the Company/Email/Phone/etc section.

The below information will be exported to CSV, so getting these paired up is crucial.

Here is my code below. Any ideas?

```
$ideas = mysql_query("SELECT itemid FROM jos_sobi2_item") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ideas)) {
    $info[] = $row['itemid'];
}

foreach($info as $item) {
$entryID = $item['itemid'];
$queryfields = mysql_query("SELECT fieldid, data_txt, itemid FROM jos_sobi2_fields_data WHERE itemid = '". $entryID ."'");
//$queryfields = mysql_query("SELECT fieldid, data_txt, itemid FROM `jos_sobi2_fields_data` WHERE `itemid` = '$entryID'");

while ($rowqueryfields = mysql_fetch_array($queryfields)) {
    $rowfields[] = $rowqueryfields;
}
foreach($rowfields as $item) {  
    // Primarily what I need is name, company and contact info such as phone, email fax web!
    $contactPerson = '9'; // Name
    $city = '3'; // City
    $state = '5'; // State
    $phone = '10'; // Phone
    $email = '7'; // Email
    $fax = '11';
    $website = '8';     

    if($item['fieldid'] == 9) {
        echo '<strong>Name: </strong>' .$item['data_txt'] . '</br>';
    }
    if($item['fieldid'] == 3) {
        //echo '<strong>City: </strong>' .$item['data_txt'] . '</br>';
    }
    if($item['fieldid'] == 5) {
        //echo '<strong>State: </strong>' .$item['data_txt'] . '</br>';
    }
    if($item['fieldid'] == 10) {
        //echo '<strong>Phone: </strong>' .$item['data_txt'] . '</br>';
    }
    if($item['fieldid'] == 7) {
        //echo '<strong>Email: </strong>' .$item['data_txt'] . '</br>';
    }
    if($item['fieldid'] == 8) {
        //echo '<strong>Website: </strong>' .$item['data_txt'] . '</br>';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: A few thoughts: you should do this in a single query with a join, switch to using mysqli (sooner than later), don't read all the rows into an array - just loop over them and process.

Comment: I am not even close to being familiar with JOIN queries. I am a novice in PHP :(

Comment: I posted something to get you started in an answer. Didn't switch to mysqli to avoid any additional confusion ;) You might want to try experimenting with the SQL query in phpmyAdmin or something to see how the results work.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use the SobiPro ImEx App?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT I.itemID, fieldid, data_txt FROM jos_sobi2_item I";
$sql .= " JOIN jos_sobi2_fields_data D on D.itemID = I.itemID";

if( $result = mysql_query( $sql ) ) {
   while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
      switch( $row['fieldid'] ) {
        case 9:
           echo '<strong>Name: </strong>' .$item['data_txt'] . '</br>';
           break;
        case 3:
           echo //whatever goes here
           break;
        // other cases
      }
   } else {
      // database error so echo or whatever

}
```

I haven't tried it so don't blame me for any minor syntax errors ;)

Hope it helps. Have fun...

Comment: This pulls information, but does not tie it together properly. While running the loop, it seems to not group up each entry's information together. I'll have to read up on this a bit.